# Generic return type and non-nullable objects

Tags: c#, .net, generics, non-nullable

I have a Sql Utility class which contains a lot of handy methods around Sql queries.
This class contains the following method:

```
public static T ExecuteScalar<T>(
    string query, 
    SqlConnection connection, 
    params SqlParameter[] parameters) 
    where T : class, new()
{
    SqlCommand command =
        CreateCommand(query, connection, parameters);

    return command.ExecuteScalar() as T;
}
```

**Is it possible to return for example `Guid` objects or other non-nullable classes.**

Something like this:

```
Guid result = 
    SqlUtils.ExecuteScalar<Guid>(
        @"SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
            WHERE [Column1] = @Param1", 
        connection, 
        new SqlParameter("@Param1", "someValue"));
```

Comment: How do you expect it to cast the object to Guid? Was it originally Guid? How was it saved?

Comment: If it's just a Guid string in the ID column, try `var guid = new Guid(SqlUtils.ExecuteScalar<string>(...));`

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but I thought the point of ExecuteScalar was to return a single value. This would mean it's never a complex class (assuming you don't count string and decimal as classes). This means it's always going to return an int, guid, datetime, etc. What's the point of the ExecuteScalar requiring the T to be a class. It makes the ExecuteScalar method worthless. The only case is if the  result returned xml. XML could be serialized into a class.

Comment: The T allows you to cast it appropriately as string vs int, etc. Otherwise it could only return "object"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `default(T)` (and you should remove the generic type constraints):

```
SqlCommand command = 
    CreateCommand(query, connection, parameters);

object value = command.ExecuteScalar();

if (value == null || value is DbNull)
{
    return default(T)'
}

return (T)value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you've written it. The `as` operator may return `null` if the cast fails, therefore `T` has to be of a reference type.

For value types, you'll need to use a conventional cast operator `(T)`. You'll also need to remove the constraint that `T` is a reference type on the method definition.

```
public static T ExecuteScalar<T>(string query, 
                             SqlConnection connection, 
                             params SqlParameter[] parameters) 
{
    SqlCommand command = CreateCommand(query, connection, parameters);
    var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result is T) return (T)result;
    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the constraints of this method return a class type, you'd be able to return any object that match a class type (non-primitive). Given the nature of your method though, I don't see any need for the constraint. You should be able to remove this constraint and return any type that you can generate.